# Source file can't see a define from other header

Tags: c, header-files, c-preprocessor, undeclared-identifier

I have a  custom header file (`"strings.h"`):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#if __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
#endif /* __cplusplus */
#include "sdkGlobal.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
#if __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif /* __cplusplus */

#if !defined administration_H_
#define administration_H_

#define POS_STR_TITLE_OPERATIONS "somestr"

#endif
```

In one of the source files I have:

```
#include "../inc/strings.h"
```

In the code when I use:

```
    sdkShow (LINE3, 0, POS_STR_TITLE_OPERATIONS );
```

I get error:

```
src/main.c: In function 'postMainMenu':
src/main.c:190: error: 'POS_STR_TITLE_OPERATIONS ' undeclared (first use in this function)
src/main.c:190: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
src/main.c:190: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[1]: *** [src/main.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the path to the header file explicitly? What directory is your code executing in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the guard should always reflect the name of the header-file to guard, so it should be "strings_H_" and "sdkGlobal_H_"

it is intended for greater products where header-files have dependencies of their own. for example "a.h" needs "length.h" and "b.h" needs "length.h" also, you guard "length.h" to be evaluated once.

Comment: yes seems that was the problem. I'd have to read more about include guards etc. as it seems I am not very "up to date" with these notions :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems `administration_H_` is already defined.So rather than

```
#if !defined administration_H_
#define administration_H_

#define POS_STR_TITLE_OPERATIONS "somestr"

#endif
```

you intended

```
#if !defined administration_H_
#define administration_H_
#endif

#if !defined POS_STR_TITLE_OPERATIONS
#define POS_STR_TITLE_OPERATIONS "somestr"
#endif
```

Comment: I could try that but before I used to have function declarations instead of `#define POS_STR_TITLE_OPERATIONS` and all seemed to work fine ..

Comment: If it's already defined then even POS_STR_TITLE_OPERATIONS  should be! It's just a normal include guard.

Comment: see my edit please. i am not a pyschic, I dont know what administration_H_ contains.

Comment: @UmNyobe: It seems to work this way but can you please explain why it was working before when I used to have function declarations instead of the `#define POS_STR_TITLE_OPERATIONS` before?

Comment: @user2568508 I would check if that include guard (administration_H_) is used somewhere else. The way you did it is right way to prevent multiple definitions.

Comment: the guard should always reflect the name of the header-file to guard, so it should be "strings_H_" and "sdkGlobal_H_"

Comment: @PeterMiehle: good point. I changed to strings_H_ - and I it seems to be working now the way I wrote initially in my question ..

Comment: @Adriano you seems to forget his file header is ***"strings.h"***. using administration_H_ as a guard is not the right thing to do

Comment: @UmNyobe I agree, that's why I suggest to check that name. What I don't agree is to use your solution. If duplicated guard name is his problem then to do in that way you just move problem to another source file (when strings.h will be included before administration.h).

Comment: I solved it by just changing to `string_H_` and leaving all as was initially (in my question)

Comment: @Adriano many programmers (including me) when reading this code will not think of `administration_H_` as a guard because it is at the middle of a header file named `strings.h`.

Comment: @UmNyobe Whatever its position is (and even its name, even this one may be really misleading) I thought `_H_` suffix is pretty explanatory! Anyway I don't think it's such important discussion...